# Multiples Log4j.xml configuration depending on scope with Spring

Tags: spring, logging, log4j2, scopes

I would like to add a different log4j.xml configuration for multiple environments (stage,prod,develop) and the idea is to add a different log level for each environment, in stage info logs, in prod errors and warnings for instance.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-log4j2 and I tried defining different log4j.xml files for each environment such as:

[image]

and in the application.properties I defined the path to these files:

for example: in the `application-develop`

```
logging.config=src/main/resources/dev/log4j.xml
```

But I'm getting the exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or is there any other way to achieve this with spring?

Comment: Try `logging.config=classpath:dev/log4j.xml`

Comment: Yes the issue was solved but now I'm not getting any log info. I deleted the main log4j.xml file and it seems like spring was using it instead of the new by scope I created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Spring solution

You can define 4 different `application-{profile}.properties` everyone with each own `logging.config={path_to_xml_file}` property.

### Out of Spring solution

According to [the official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

Log4j has the ability to automatically configure itself during initialization. When Log4j starts it will locate all the ConfigurationFactory plugins and arrange them in weighted order from highest to lowest. As delivered, Log4j contains four ConfigurationFactory implementations: one for JSON, one for YAML, one for properties, and one for XML.

- Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension. Note that this is not restricted to a location on the local file system and may contain a URL
- If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
- If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
- If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
- If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
- If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
- If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath.
- If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
- If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
- If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.